# Android Service's onBind isn't being called and onDestroy is being called even with a client connected

Tags: android, android-service

In my app, I have a Service that is used to play music of a MP3 stream.
I start it (startService()) and connect to it (bindService()), so it doesn't stop when there's no client connected.
If the player is paused, I clean some resources after some time and, if it remains paused for some more time, I clean almost all the resources and: if there's no client connected (Activitys connected), I stop the service calling stopSelf(); if there's some client connected, I prepare it to be destroyed, setting a boolean that is checked when all the clients disconnect, calling stopSelf() if there's no client connected and this boolean is true.

So, basically, the service is destroyed only if (1) there's no client connected to it AND (2) it's paused for a long time.

It's working well, but I have an issue. In onDestroy(), I release all the resources and save some data (like the list of musics that was being played). If there's many musics, it can take almost half a second. The problem is when I open again my app exactly in this period of time, when the onDestroy() hasn't returned yet. What happens is that the same service's instance is used and onCreate() isn't called. So, since the resources were released, naturally I get some errors.

This bug is very hard to simulate. I was able to reproduce just 3 times. I don't know how to proceed. I thought of returning from the onDestroy() as fast as I can, using another thread to release the resources and save the data, but it would make the new service to be started before the data has been saved. Does someone know more details about the way the destroy/recreate of a service is done on Android? I don't know which class manages it, so I don't know which code I could read to understand it better.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I've just found my real problem. It seems that the Service's onBind isn't being called when my Activity disconnects and reconnects (when I close all the Activities and open the app again). So, my resource cleaner (that is a scheduled job that is scheduled for some time later when the player is paused)  thinks there's no client connected and calls stopSelf() (I keep track of the connected clients using the onBind and onUnbind methods). And, even that there's a client connected to the service, the onDestroy() is called. Then, my Activity keeps connected to the Service that just cleaned all the resources.

I've updated the question's title as well.

UPDATE 2:

Just a little more explanation. When I close and reopen my app, the method onServiceConnected of my ServiceConnection's implementation is called after the bindService, but the onBind of the Service isn't called. And it's seems that it really thinks there's no client connected, since it gets destroyed even that the documentation says that a started and bound service wouldn't be destroyed until all the clients unbind.

Comment: you can release resources and save data not in activity onDestroy method, but in service onDestroy method.

Comment: in service onDestroy method you can start releasing resources and saving data, at this moment write somewhere flag that work is started (in SharedPreferences, or somewhere else), then in your activity check if flag = true - start background thread and sleep for 3 sec for example and check flag again. when work will be finished your background thread will restart your service.

Comment: I'm talking about Service's onDestroy(), not Activity's onDestroy(). The Activity is just unbinding from the service. When the onUnbind() is called I do the verifications I've said.

Comment: Hum... I'll think about it. Maybe this idea of checking if the Service has been destroyed already would work.

Comment: Or you can send broadcast when onDestroy method finished his job, react to this broadcast in your activity and start Service again.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji, I've updated my question. Do you have any idea about problem?

Comment: where are registered your clients? are you using IPC through Messenger? Add check in Service class in onDestroy method - if there is connected clients, do not start resource cleaner.

Comment: Since this Service is used in a lot of Activities, I have a class that is extended by the others. This class takes care of connecting with the service. It calls startService and bindService. The Service is already keeping track of the connected clients using the onBind and onUnbind. If there's any client connected, it doesn't stop the service. I've found out that the onBind wasn't being called when I was reconnecting. So, I started to return true in onUnbind and implemented the onRebind too. Now, I'm able to know if there's any client connected.

Comment: But it's very strange. The documentation clearly says that a service that is both started and bound is not destroyed until all the clients are disconnected. So, even when my resource cleaner calls stopSelf(), it shouldn't stop.

Comment: In Android are many strange situations like you have :) it's fun open source project, which we (developers) trying to make better and better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that my onBind wasn't being called when reconnected with the Service. So, I started to return 'true' in the onUnbind. This way, the onRebind is called when the Activity reconnects to the Service. Then, I'm still keeping track if there's any client connected and my resource cleaner just calls stopSelf if there's no client connected.

Anyway, I think it is a bug. The documentation tells me that a Service that is both started (startService()) and bound (bindService()) isn't destroyed (onDestroy()) until both all clients are disconnected and the stopService/stopSelf is called. So, when my resource cleaner calls stopSelf(), the service shouldn't be destroyed, since there's a client connected (when the client reconnects).